# Turtle screen click doesn't work with a while loop

Tags: python, onclick, turtle-graphics

When I run the program, it begins printing 0. When I click on the turtle screen, it goes to not responding mode.

I've already tried putting the `while True` within the function. I also tried putting `onscreenclick` after the loop.

```
from turtle import*
v=0
def g(x,y):
    global v
    v=v+5
onscreenclick(g)
while True:
    print(v)
```

I expected it to begin printing 5 after the first click, 10 after the second and but turtle goes to not responding mode while printing continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entire program is wrong-headed turtle-wise.  But, I'll save that lecture and simply say don't use `while True:` in an event-based world like turtle.  Instead use an `ontimer` event:

```
from turtle import *

v = 0

def g(x, y):
    global v
    v += 5

onscreenclick(g)

def repeat():
    print(v)
    ontimer(repeat, 100)

repeat()

mainloop()
```